# How to set constructor parameters before deploying in remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

I don’t understand how it works. I created a contract with a constructor with parameters. But I don’t understand where to pass these parameters to the constructor. Or I need to set params after deploying? Please, explain me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enter them in the field next to the Deploy button, separated by commas.

[image: Next to deploy button]

Or you can expand this field and you get individual fields for each parameter.

[image: Expanded]